# in javascript I'm using EventListener and I get the TypeError xyz = null

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

//This is the code I am using. In the console I get the error TypeError xyz = null, please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
<script>
var xyz = document.getElementById("myBtn");

xyz.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverExample1);
xyz.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverExample2);

function hoverExample1() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";}

function hoverExample2() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";}
</script>

<body>
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Hover Experiment 1</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your `<script>` as `last-child` of `<body>` instead of placing it in `<head>`. By the time you are accessing <kbd>`myBtn`</kbd>, it is not there in the `DOM`

```js
var xyz = document.getElementById("myBtn");

xyz.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverExample1);
xyz.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverExample2);

function hoverExample1() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

function hoverExample2() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Hover Experiment 1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This js script being executed even before DOM is ready & at that point  `#myBtn` is not available. As mentioned in previous answer you can put your script at the end of `body` tag or else you can make you snippet to execute on `window.onload`
while still placing your js before the html part

```
window.onload = _attachEvent; // a function to wrap all js code 
                                 and it will be called onload
function _attachEvent(){
var xyz = document.getElementById("myBtn");

xyz.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverExample1);
xyz.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverExample2);

function hoverExample1() {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
   }
function hoverExample2() {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
}
```

You can also explore [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) which can also be used to resolve such issue.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/v4nnwewb/1/)